# Is there any way to classify text without target labels?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I was wondering if there was any way to classify text data into different groups/categories based on the words in the text using a combination of Python and Sklearn Machine Learning?

For example:

```
text = [["request approval for access", "request approval to enter premises", "Laptop not working"], ["completed bw table loading"]]
```

So can I get categories like:

```
category_label = [[0,0,2], [1]]
categories = [["approval request", "approval request", "Laptop working"], ["bw table"]]
```

where

```
  0 = approval request
  2 = laptop working
  1 = bw table
```

Basically the above would imply that there is no labelled training data or target labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is readily possible in [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) as well as in [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/).

The features that you list:

```
0 = approval request
2 = laptop working
1 = bw table
```

are not ones that a clustering algorithm would naturally choose and its worthwhile to caution you against the possible mistake of clouding your statistical learning algorithm with heuristics.  I suggest that you first try some clustering and classification and then consider [semi-supervised learning methods](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html) whereby you can label your clusters and propagate those labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a clustering method but there is no guarantee that the clusters you get will correspond to the categories you want, because you haven't clearly explained the algorithm what you want.

What I would do is manually label some data (how long can it take to label 300 samples?) and train on that, so that your algo can learn the words the are correlated with each class.

If this is impossible then your best bet is to calculate a cosine similarity between one sample and each class description, rank them, and then assign the closest class. But in my opinion by the time you finish to code this, you could have manually labeled some samples and trained a standard algo with a much better precision.

Comment: I have used K-Means Algorithm to cluster the data. But the clustering isn't all that accurate. Which is where I thought I would use DBSCAN (with an eps = 0.85)to further cluster the already Kmeans clusters. This works in theory....but the records inside some of those DBSCAN sub clusters is just 1. Which would make my actual complete code a bit hacky. So wanted to avoid that. For me to label the data manually is impossible because the data size is huge!

Comment: You don't need to label all the data, just a couple samples to train the algo. Then use the trained algo to predict the rest.

Comment: In addition to the 'eps' parameter, which sets the maximum distance for two points to be in the same neighborhood, sk-learn's DBSCAN algorithm has a 'min_samples' paramter which sets the minimum number of samples for a neighborhood.  This parameter defaults to 5, so I'm surprised that you are seeing core clusters with only one member.

Comment: @AN6U5 OMG! You're right! I had set the min_samples to 1! Thank you for pointing that out!